# Insert in sqlite doesn't work

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i'm trying to make insert call to add row to my table in sqlite code,
every time insert return 1, and also after i insert row i check that the row was insert and it can't be found.

here is my code:

**create tables:**

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // create table artists
        String createTableStatement1 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ARTISTS +" ("+ KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "
                                    + KEY_ARTIST_NAME + " TEXT UNIQUE , " + KEY_ARTIST_IMAGE + " BLOB, " + KEY_ARTIST_JSON + " TEXT, "
                                    + KEY_ARTIST_DATE + " DATETIME DEFAULT (datetime('now')), " + KEY_ARTIST_FLAG + " INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT 1);";
        db.execSQL(createTableStatement1);


        //creat table users
        String createTableStatement2 = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_USERS + " ("+ KEY_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE, "
                + KEY_PROFILE_ID + " TEXT UNIQUE, " + KEY_PROFILE_JSON + " TEXT, "+ KEY_PROFILE_IMAGE + " BLOB, " + KEY_PROFILE_FLAG 
                + " INTEGER NOT NULL);";
        db.execSQL(createTableStatement2);

    }
```

**upgrade tables**

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ARTISTS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

**insert user row**

```
public void insertUserToDB(User user)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_PROFILE_FLAG, user.getProfile_flag());
        values.put(KEY_PROFILE_IMAGE, user.getProfileImageByteArray());
        values.put(KEY_PROFILE_JSON, user.getProfile_json());
        values.put(KEY_PROFILE_ID, user.getProfile_id());

        db.beginTransaction();
        long result = db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_USERS, null, values);

        db.endTransaction();
        db.close();


    }
```

**check user in database**

```
public boolean isUserInDB(String profileID)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        String sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_USERS +" WHERE " + TABLE_USERS + "."+ KEY_PROFILE_ID +
                                "="  + "\""+ profileID + "\"";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sqlStatement, null);
        boolean exists = ((cursor.getCount())!=0);
        cursor.close();
        db.endTransaction();
        db.close();

        return exists;
    }
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [`setTransactionSuccessful()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setTransactionSuccessful()) to make the `endTransaction()` apply your changes.

Comment: Also note that a transaction is not useful, if you only perform a single command on a db. A transaction comes to help when you perform more operations: CONFIRM them all or FAIL them all.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction()

```
   db.beginTransaction();
   try {
     ...
     db.setTransactionSuccessful();
   } finally {
     db.endTransaction();
   }
```

The `db.setTransactionSuccessful();` method is the most important part because it confirms the save of entire transactions. Without this call you will get no change in your database.